# NSFileManager- fileExistsAtPath, Paths case sensitivity or insensivity issue in iOS 11

Tags: ios, ios11, nsfilemanager

My app downloads images in a folder that is created dynamically. This folder does not follow strict
naming pattern,sometimes folder's name is in upper case sometimes in lower case. Now if there is an image "XYZ" in folder named "A" then filesystem throws error if I try to access "a/XYZ". Prior to iOS 11 it was working fine. I can not make everything uppercase or lowercase. Need some work around so that fileexistatPath ignores case.